# Issue with adding new Item dynamically in vue-responsive-dash

Tags: javascript, vue.js, react-grid-layout

I'm working with [vue-responsive-dash](https://vue-responsive-dash.netlify.app/) library to display responsive tiles in a grid though I'm having an issue while adding a new item by clicking a button.
It works fine if I don't resize the item. After spending a few hours I figured out the placeholder item places itself just after the first item.

You can reproduce issue here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-responsive-dash-wbgs8

**Steps:**

1. Click "Add" button and add first item.
2. Resize the added item.
3. Click "Add" button to add another item.
4. See the space between first and second item.**

Is there something I can do to remove this space?

Comment: Looks like an issue with the library where it doesn't recalculate positioning based on the resized area.  It looks like you've already opened an issue on the repo?  That's going to be the best way to get it fixed.

Comment: I want a quick fix for specific issue.

Comment: As David said, the best thing you could have done is create an issue on the repo. As it's likely a library related bug, nobody will be able to fix this externally. Be patient or try to fix this yourself and more importantly: be indulgent. It's free open source, and maintainers are not paid to fix this :)